# Which word fits better in this case: focused, aimed or oriented?

Tags: word-choice

- My research is focused to find life in other planets.
- My research is aimed to find life in other planets.
- My research is oriented to find life in other planets.

In formal writing, which one is better and why? Also is it better *to* or *on*?

Comment: None of these examples strike me as valid. All choices of verb are acceptable, and I see no reason to favour one over another. But they should be, for example, *is focussed on finding, aims at finding, is oriented towards finding*.

Comment: And it should be ***on** other planets*; we already know next to nothing about life **in** the Earth. Almost all the life we know about is **on** the Earth. And clearly any life we discover on exoplanets is going to be on their surface.

Answer (score 1):

The three options all sound slightly like business "buzzwords" out of place.

Perhaps this is more simple and therefore better: "The purpose of my research is to find life on other planets".

Answer (score 0):

FumbleFingers is definitely giving you the right advice: use gerunds.

Avoid "focussed", it is an overused buzzword with so little of its original meaning left to it. You focus light and energy, not research.

But above all, David Aldridge "hits your nail on the head". If that's what you are trying to say, he's saying it perfectly.